# DELETE request for organizations does not require auth token

Tags: fiware, fiware-keyrock

I've noticed when you are about to delete an organization the suggested request in [docu is this one](https://fiware-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/identity-management/index.html#organization-crud-actions) (subsection *DELETE AN ORGANIZATION* inside *ORGANIZATION CRUD ACTIONS*):

```
curl -iX DELETE \
  'http://localhost:3005/v1/organizations/{{organization-id}}' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
```

Which does not include the `X-Auth-token` as part of the header.

Could this result in a security issue (allowing anyone to delete any organization)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command for delete of organization in the referenced [document](https://fiware-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/identity-management/index.html#organization-crud-actions) is incomplete.

```
curl -iX DELETE \
  'http://localhost:3005/v1/organizations/{{organization-id}}' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
```

the `X-Auth-Token` in the above mentioned command is missing, without `X-Auth-Token` one will not be able to delete the oraganization or perform any other operations.

The command without `X-Auth-Token` will have the following response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Expecting to find X-Auth-token in requests",
        "code": 400,
        "title": "Bad Request"
    }
}
```

The correct command will have X-Auth-Token in its header:

```
curl -iX DELETE \
      'http://localhost:3005/v1/organizations/{{organization-id}}' \
      -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
      -H 'X-Auth-Token: {{X-Auth-Token}}
```

the above command(with `X-Auth-Token`) will have response with Http Status `HTTP/1.1 204 No Content`

Screenshot:
[image: response]
[image: response]

Comment: First ... thank you so much. I would have assume that docu was incomplete if not were because [here](https://keyrock.docs.apiary.io/#reference/keyrock-api/organization/delete-an-organization) is also incomplete. But anyway, of course the better way to check this was trying it. I think both sites must be completed.

Comment: The [tutorial](https://fiware-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/identity-management/index.html#organization-crud-actions) has now been updated

Comment: @JasonFox I think you should update the [apiary reference](https://keyrock.docs.apiary.io/#reference/keyrock-api/organization/delete-an-organization) maybe this is more relevant than tutorial.

Comment: The apiary definition is not under my control - I have raised an [issue](https://github.com/ging/fiware-idm/issues/117) on the relevant GitHub repository which should make the development team aware.